# Siemens Type QN mounting screw size?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, screws

I have a QN2200R breaker without the little screw it came with that screws into the panel to hold the breaker in place.  Does anyone know the size of screw or if Siemens sells a replacement screw kit?  I can't seem to find any information about the screw on the documentation for the breaker.

It's this little screw from this picture:
[image]

Comment: metric.................

Comment: A local electrical supply shop should have it, or at least know the size so you can go to your local hardware store to get it.  Wild guess is a self tapping two and a half to three inch 8-32 or 10-32 screw.  Do not go by this till you have a positive ID.